# I have XSLT code and Input file(XML).But I am getting below error.Please find the below XSLT code and Input file.Kindly tell me the issue

Tags: xslt

I am using below XSL to parse the sample input message.
Below I have given the sample xsl and xml and error message.

Please tell me the what is the issue?

Please find the below XSLT code and Input file(XML)....

**XSLT Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                xmlns="http://www.openapplications.org/oagis/9"
                xmlns:fn="http://www.logiasoftware.fi/LGW/functions"
                xmlns:tns="http://www.logiasoftware.fi/message/Transportation/2011/01"
                xmlns:cdm2="http://www.logiasoftware.fi/schema/Transportation/2011/01"
                xmlns:date="java.util.Date"
                xmlns:comm="http://www.logiasoftware.fi/schema/Common/2011/01" xmlns:FI="urn:tieke:names:tc:ubl:Fi-TransportOrder:1:0"
                xmlns:fi-cac="urn:tieke:names:tc:ubl:Fi-CAC-Tieke:1:0" xmlns:cur="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:codelist:CurrencyCode:1:0"
                xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CoreComponentParameters:1:0" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CommonBasicComponents:1:0" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CommonAggregateComponents:1:0"
                exclude-result-prefixes="fn" xmlns:my="functions" xmlns:ex="http://exslt.org/dates-and-times" extension-element-prefixes="ex">

    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="Guid" select="concat(Waybill/WaybillID, '_', my:CleanDateTime(current-dateTime()))"/>

    <xsl:template match="Waybill" mode="transform">
        <tns:ShipmentInformationMessage>
            <tns:TestIndicator>
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="contains(upper-case(WaybillID), 'TEST')">
                        <xsl:value-of select="true()"/>
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>
                        <xsl:value-of select="false()"/>
                    </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </tns:TestIndicator>
            <tns:Action>
                <xsl:text>new</xsl:text>
            </tns:Action>
            <tns:Shipments>
                <tns:Shipment>
                    <cdm2:MasterSystemId>
                       <xsl:text>ETRABookingInbound</xsl:text>
                    </cdm2:MasterSystemId>
                    <cdm2:OwnerId>
                       <xsl:value-of select="ConsignorParty/cac:PartyIdentification/cac:ID"/>
                    </cdm2:OwnerId>
                    <cdm2:TrackingCode>
                       <xsl:value-of select="WaybillID"/>
                    </cdm2:TrackingCode>
                    <cdm2:DatesAndTimes>
                        <cdm2:ShipmentDateTime>
                         <xsl:choose>   
                            <xsl:when test="cbc:IssueDate != ''">
                               <xsl:value-of select="my:ConvertDateTimeToCDM2(cbc:IssueDate)"/>
                            </xsl:when>
                            <xsl:otherwise>
                                <xsl:value-of select="ex:date-time()"/>
                            </xsl:otherwise>
                        </xsl:choose>
                        </cdm2:ShipmentDateTime>
                    </cdm2:DatesAndTimes>
                </tns:Shipment>
            </tns:Shipments>
        </tns:ShipmentInformationMessage>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Input XML file**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Waybill xmlns="urn:tieke:names:tc:ubl:Fi-TransportOrder:1:0" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" xmlns:udt="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:UnspecializedDatatypes:1:0" xmlns:sdt="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:SpecializedDatatypes:1:0"
         xmlns:res="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:codelist:AcknowledgementResponseCode:1:0" xmlns:fi-cac="urn:tieke:names:tc:ubl:Fi-CAC-Tieke:1:0" xmlns:cur="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:codelist:CurrencyCode:1:0"
         xmlns:ccts="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CoreComponentParameters:1:0" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CommonBasicComponents:1:0" xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:tc:ubl:CommonAggregateComponents:1:0">
    <WaybillID>300102</WaybillID>
    <WaybillType>700</WaybillType>
    <cbc:IssueDate>2014-02-21</cbc:IssueDate>
    <cbc:Note>9</cbc:Note>
    <TotalTransportHandlingUnitsQuantity quantityUnitCode="kpl">3</TotalTransportHandlingUnitsQuantity>
    <cbc:GrossWeightMeasure measureUnitCode="kg">41.3</cbc:GrossWeightMeasure>
    <cbc:GrossVolumeMeasure measureUnitCode="m3">.35</cbc:GrossVolumeMeasure>
    <AdditionalDocumentReference>
        <cac:ID>539</cac:ID>
    </AdditionalDocumentReference>
    <ConsignorParty>
        <cac:PartyIdentification>
            <cac:ID>003701078010</cac:ID>
        </cac:PartyIdentification>
    </ConsigneeParty>
</Waybill>
```

**Output(Error)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><SOAP-ENV:Envelope encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:rpc="http://www.sonicsw.com/sonicxq/rpc" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
<xq:rejectedMessageInfo xmlns:xq="http://www.sonicsw.com/sonicxq">
<rejectedCode>XQ_SERVICE_EXCEPTION</rejectedCode>
<rejectedLocation container="cntFreight_ETRA" host="tntmqdit" process="ETRABookingInbound" serviceApplication="freight.ETRABookingInbound.Transform2" step="ETRAToTMSSystem" topLevelProcess="ETRABookingInbound"/>
<rejectedDetails>com.sonicsw.xq.XQServiceException: Failed to transform XQMessage part, index=0 (Error reported by XML parser; Line#: 4; Column#: 200 cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Waybill'.) (Error reported by XML parser; Line#: 4; Column#: 200 cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'Waybill'.)
    at com.sonicsw.xq.service.common.SAXEngine.runTransform(SAXEngine.java:470)
    at com.sonicsw.xq.service.common.SAXEngine.xform(SAXEngine.java:339)
    at com.sonicsw.xq.service.xform.Xformer.apply(Xformer.java:521)
    at com.sonicsw.xq.service.xform.Xformer.processMessage(Xformer.java:393)
    at com.sonicsw.xq.service.xform.Xformer.processRules(Xformer.java:234)
</rejectedDetails>
</xq:rejectedMessageInfo>   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: You have better odds to get help if you show the least amount of your own work. Try to narrow down the problem. Remove the SOAP layer and try to reproduce the error on a command line. Remove some code from your xslt and/or from your xml. Find the smallest example that still reproduces the error. Then paste that. Or maybe you will happen to find the cause yourself in that process.

Answer (score 0):

I've not used your particular XML/XSL framework before, but looking at the output, the error is saying "Cannot find the declaration of element 'Waybill'".

Looking at the XML, that element has a default namespace:

```
<Waybill xmlns="urn:tieke:names:tc:ubl:Fi-TransportOrder:1:0" />
```

The XSLT declares the namespace, but does not use it in the template match element:

```
<xsl:stylesheet ...
                xmlns:FI="urn:tieke:names:tc:ubl:Fi-TransportOrder:1:0"
                ... >
    <xsl:template match="Waybill" mode="transform">
       ...
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Does that error go away if you use the namespace in your match?

```
<xsl:template match="FI:Waybill" mode="transform">
   ...
</xsl:template>
```

Generally, the namespaces used in your XML should match with those used in your XPath statements - unless you specifically write the XPath to say "match the element name and ignore the namespace".